# routing is too verbose - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Suppose I have a model `User` and I want to add some `dashboard` namespace. So I create `dashbord` directory and put inside `private_users_controller.rb`. Now for routing I put

```
namespace "dashboard" do
    resources :users do
      member do
        get "show" => "private_users#show"
      end
    end
  end
```

the problem is that I only want to route the get request having this route `/dashboard/users/:id/show`. But `rake routes` shows a bunch of `post`, `delete`... routes. 
How can I cut those ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like you don't need any of the method from resources definition, so just add a match will be ok.

```
namespace "dashboard" do
  match 'users/:id/show', :to => 'private_users#show'
end
```

if you insist using resource, then the following will work

```
scope '/dashboard' do
    resources :users, :only => :show, :module => 'private'
end
```

the 'rake routes' output is like this

```
GET    /dashboard/users/:id(.:format)        private/users#show
```

the trailing 'show' inside the url is not needed.

Comment: thank you but it still create a route `dashboard_user GET      /dashboard/users/:id(.:format) dashboard/users#show`

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace "dashboard" do
  get "users/:id/show" => "private_users#show"
end
```